# "Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed Error:Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected" While importinng project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to import a project in android studio it end up saying

Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed
Error:Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected.

Can I know whats the reason for the issue how to overcome this and make the project import. Tried cleaning and deleting .gradle files but issue persist.

Comment: do you have any other error information?

Comment: No other information nor pointing to any line in code

Comment: If this project is not very big, keep in mind the extreme solution: create a new project adding files manually